# How to find html object in the document?

Tags: javascript

I create an HTML object using such code:

```
var parseHTML = function(str) {
  var tmp = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
  tmp.body.innerHTML = str;
  return tmp.body.children;
};

var htmlCollection = parseHTML('<div><article><h1>Article heading</h1></article></div>');
var articleNode = htmlCollection[0].childNodes[0];
```

In my html code I also have such element:

```
<article>
    <h1>Article heading</h1>
</article>
```

So the question is: how can I find `article` element in my html document using `articleNode`?

Non-jQuery solution is preferred.

**UPD:** `articleNode` and article in the html are two separate elements. I need to reference the second one using the first one

**UPD2** Use-case: I send `document.location` in an ajax request, and receive html code (as a string) for contents of 'content part' of the page from which the requestwas sent (I apologize for the tautology). Then I need to get the CSS path for that `content` container. That's why I convert string to html object and trying to find it in the document.

Comment: `articleNode` is the article element... are you experiencing something different?

Comment: @PatrickEvans `articleNode` and article in the html are two separate elements. I need to reference the second one using the first one.

Comment: You can't, the second article is not in the same document as the first. Maybe reedit your question to be more clear of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @PatrickEvans, yep, that's why I wondered if there is any way to do it.

Comment: @PatrickEvans use-case added

Answer (score 0):

If you return the document fragment, you can query it using `querySelector[All], something like:

```js
window.onload = function () {

  var parseHTML = function(str) {
    var tmp = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
    tmp.body.innerHTML = str;
    return tmp;
  };

  var htmlCollection = parseHTML('<div><article><h1>Article heading</h1>'+
                                 '</article><article><h1>Article heading 2</h1>'+
                                 '</article></div>');
  var result = document.querySelector('#result');
  var articleNodes = htmlCollection.querySelectorAll('div, article');

  result.innerHTML = 'first article: '+articleNodes[1].outerHTML+'<br>';
  result.innerHTML += 'the whole enchilada: '+articleNodes[0].outerHTML;
  
};
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I do not need to edit the html document. I just need to find where the `atricleNode` is in my html document

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify what exactly you want to achieve?